# Why I'm not geting proper date comparison result in following situation?

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp, strtotime, date-comparison

My code is as follows:

```
if(!empty($form_data["birth_date"])){
          $date1   = date('d/m/y');

          $tempArr = explode('/', $form_data["birth_date"]);
          $date2   = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $tempArr[1] ,$tempArr[0], $tempArr[2]));

        }

if(strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($date1)) 
          echo "Please enter date which is not greater than today's date!!!";
```

I'm getting the error message even after entering the date less than today's date. I'm using dd/mm/yyyy format. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

```
$date1 = 20/12/2013;

$date2 = 21/03/1985;
```

Comment: Can you show the values, you are checking?

Comment: See what you get on values of two dates

Comment: @DainisAbols:I've added the values I'm comparing(before converting to timestamp) to the question.

Comment: And what is `$form_data["birth_date"]` input?

Comment: @DainisAbols: It's value of $date2

Comment: Change the type from `d/m/y` to `m/d/y`.

Answer (score 3):

strtotime function is used to date format YYYY/MM/DD so please convert date this formate and then apply strtotime() and after  compare two dates

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.`

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime function for this . Try like this :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("12/12/2013 21:00:02");

var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
```

OUTPUT:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: But I don't want to send the time as an argument as you didi in second line of your code.

Comment: You cannot use `d/m/Y` format in `strtotime()` or `new DateTime()`, since it is not valid standard format; php parse assumes it is `m/d/Y`, thats why error will rise when you try to enter day bigger than 12, like `21/12/2013`.